# TailwindCSS purge css files seperately

Tags: css, gulp, tailwind-css, postcss

Consider `page1.html` with `tailwind1.css` and `page2.html` with `tailwind2.css` and the `tailwind.config.js` below:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: true,
    content: ['./*.html']
  },
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

and the Gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')

gulp.task('css', function () {
    const postcss = require('gulp-postcss')

    return gulp.src('css/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss([
            require('postcss-import'),
            require('tailwindcss'),
            require('autoprefixer'),
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
})
```

Purge here works and cleans both `tailwind1.css` and `tailwind2.css`. However, both css files will "carry" all styles for `page1.html` and `page2.html`.

Is there any way to purge these css files separately for the 2 html files? At the end `tailwind1.css` should contain only what `page1.html` uses (same for page2)

Comment: Make two tasks? One with `return gulp.src('css/tailwind1.css')` and the other with `return gulp.src('css/tailwind2.css')`?

Comment: @Dominik Yes but `content: ['./*.html']` in `tailwind.config.ks` will still target both html files.